# How to find a single event in Modelica?

Tags: loops, events, modelica

Please help me with a simple task.

I have the function delta=f(time). See the picture.

[image]

I need to find value of "time" when "delta" became zero and assign the time's value to some parameter.
For example-I can see on the picture that the time which match with delta=0 is approximately 9.3. I can assign to Real variable X=9.3. 
But can I do it automatically? I mean can Modelica can asign 9.3 to X?

P.S. I use when/while/if statement, but they works until duration, but I need to find a single event (when delta=0).

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand your PS.  A `when` clause is the way to do this, and it is simple:

```
Real X;
equation
when delta<=0 then
  X := time;
end when;
```

What's the problem with that?

Comment: Hello Michael ! Thank for your answer, your book and your twitter-I read all of them and I'm very interested in.) 

The problem is when I use "when" clause I get the gap variable (see the picture below).  But I want to find exactly 9.3 value (as a constant without gap). Does it clear? http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=25852cefe1a14f61428b296eea02dd94

Comment: Two things to consider.  First, use `<=` vs. `<`.  But more importantly, the solver is *numerical* so it cannot solve exactly.  So it solves within some *tolerance*.  You can specify that tolerance (how to do this varies from tool to tool, but all of them allow you to specify it).  So try tightening your tolerances.  Good luck.